# c# winforms - is InitializeComponent() function calling while refresh?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

I want to ask about function `InitializeComponent()`. Is called after `Invalidate()` - invalidating component?

Version: .net 4.5, VS 2012

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `InitializeComponent()` is only ever called in the constructor.

That is, unless you decide to call it yourself from within one of your methods.

There is no interface, nor base class that requires your form to have a method called `InitializeComponent()`, it's just that's what Visual Studio's WinForms designer calls the method.

Comment: One little question about `refresh()` function. Does it refresh its components (I mean buttons, etc. and if it calls refresh function on each component)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have InitializeComponent() method call only in form constructor, than it is called only once, while initializing form.

If you manualy added InitializeComponent() in another place, for example, before you call Invalidate(), than yes.

Answer (score 0):

The `"InitializeComponent"` must be called once at the constructor. The reason this function exists is to separate the designer code initialization and your implementation. It does all the new things for private variables generated with the designer. You can see the implementation of the function by hittin F12 on it.

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: thanks, of course it helps :) .. I've tried to look into declaration, but I've got lost after while.

Comment: Let it be as it is and do not try to understand what it is because I think there are many important things to focus on. Cheers bro.